# Reducing typing in class with special methods

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to reduce redundancy in my typescript typing. I am creating a specific type of class where:

- Each method within the class has one parameter
- For each parameter key, there is a corresponding method
- The parameter (first & only) from that corresponding method are also allowed in this method.

Here's a working example of a class:

```
interface Wood {}
interface Chair {}
interface DiningRoom {}
interface LivingRoom {}
interface Nail {}

class House {

    constructor () {

    }

    wood (i: {tree: string}): Wood {
        return {}
    }

    nails (i: {nails: number}): Nail[] {
        return [{}]
    }

    chair (i: {wood: Wood, nails: Nail[]} 
        & Parameters<House['wood']>[0]
        & Parameters<House['nails']>[0]    
    ): Chair {
        return {}
    }

    diningRoom (i: {chair: Chair } & Parameters<House['chair']>[0]): DiningRoom {
        return {}
    }

    livingRoom (i: {chair: Chair } & Parameters<House['chair']>[0]): LivingRoom {
        return {}
    }

}
```

I am looking for either a *abstract class* or *generic type* that would make it less redundant to write `& Parameters<House['wood']>[0]`. Ideally an abstract class that would be able to see `i: {chair: Chair}` as the parameter and know to add `& Parameters<House['chair']>[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you're doing, and I have no idea if it's possible to do anything with inheritance that would make it possible to have subclass method parameters intersect with things automatically.  As far as I can tell, the generic type corresponding to your parameters looks something like this:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type MakeParam<H extends Record<K, (x: any) => any>, K extends keyof any> =
  { [Q in K]: Parameters<H[Q]>[0] }[K] extends infer L ?
  { [Q in AllKeys<L>]: Extract<L, Record<Q, any>>[Q] } extends infer M ?
  { [P in K | keyof M]:
    (P extends keyof M ? M[P] : unknown) &
    (P extends K ? ReturnType<H[P]> : unknown)
  } : never : never;
```

You use it like this:

```
type Test = MakeParam<House, "wood">;
/* type Test = {
    wood: Wood;
    tree: string;
} */
```

or for multiple keys, as a union like this:

```
type Test2 = MakeParam<House, "wood" | "nails">;
/* type Test2 = {
    wood: Wood;
    nails: number & Nail[];
    tree: string;
} */
```

Notice that `number & Nail[]`.  That's weird and useless, but is exactly what your current code requires, so there you go.  Presumably the object you pass into the `nails()` method should not have a key named `nails`.  Duplicates will be intersected; use at your own risk.

Then you can refactor your `House` definition like this:

```
class House {

  constructor() {
  }

  wood(i: { tree: string }): Wood {
    return {}
  }

  nails(i: { nails: number }): Nail[] {
    return [{}]
  }

  chair(i: MakeParam<House, "wood" | "nails">): Chair {
    return {}
  }

  diningRoom(i: MakeParam<House, "chair">): DiningRoom {
    return {}
  }

  livingRoom(i: MakeParam<House, "chair">): LivingRoom {
    return {}
  }

}
```

And it works the same as your given code, I think.

---

I suppose you want an explanation for `MakeParam<H, K>`.  That could get really wordy, so I'm just going to give a sketch:

- `{ [Q in K]: Parameters<H[Q]>[0] }[K] extends infer L ? ... : never`

  This defines a type `L` which is the union of all the parameters for the methods named in the `K` union.  When `H` is `House` and `K` is `"wood" | "nails"`, you get `{ tree: string } | { nails: number }`.
- `{ [Q in AllKeys<L>]: Extract<L, Record<Q, any>>[Q] } extends infer M ? ... : never`

  This defines a type `M` which takes `L` and turns the union into an "intersection" by extracting all the properties from all union pieces.  When `H` is `House` and `K` is `"wood" | "nails"`, you get `{ tree: string, nails: number }`.
- `{ [P in K | keyof M]: (P extends keyof M ? M[P] : unknown) & (P extends K ? ReturnType<H[P]> : unknown) }`

  This makes a new object with all the properties from `M`, and also adds properties with names in `K` and types as the return type of the methods named by `K`.  Generally each property name should only appear in either `K` or `keyof M`, and if I knew that for sure I'd have done something like `M[P] | ReturnType<H[P]>` (with some `keyof` checks to make that compiler), but your `nails` definition gave me pause and I had to make sure it behaved the same as your current thing, with the fun `number & Nail[]` type coming out.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=39&ssc=14&pln=39&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoHt0BNkG9kDuA-AFzIDOYUoA5sgL4CwAUKJLIigMIAWcwUPMgSkKVWgxZto8JMgAioWgCVMAWyFZRlaiDpNW4GZ2QAZYADcV6oQBtt4vZMPtZKAHL9bQkA936WFjAATwAHFABBW1sAaQhg8gAeABUAPmQAXmRk5AgAD0gQLHJkOBBg5CJkAGt49Bhs5DIQCAtoAG4gsJQAWThagAU4KDg1RIAJXIKIIpLlCAR0KCxEmIAaZAAKPLIy4IBKTPS91I2YqcLimrqGk8yWZCEAbQBFZFBkGIBdMiGRtQg7CS41eX1STwADF8GE9vhcZldQDBoGZKg9nm8PlFYvEkqZUj9kABRAojBBgRKmDbzRbLRIvDYncEvaH0eGzd4gZGCHpo5iPfBPAacz7IAA+12C9WQPR+6Mem2F+UuJVqUoavKqPSF0LIAFcQNUQOgCCBDgAyeVbJXTDnnKrzMB6qAgZLdCY69L6w3G037dFs5qtFFBtpQTrMLrhbIQSiZGX9CB-UYTdB68gQDYAIgImCwWdSEYA9AAqZAhaPJWNgeO4K257BkDDYCOPR5UCAQMg6WgRtklouBZgVlBVygAJnjfUGwxT4zTGezDfz4uQWZAXnIBeLZZHMYntfreabedbbY3wFs5GaerUACMUebkJ5L08vmf21BO93HDQ+8gByHFgEFsOByBKed0xQOtI35YR0BAHQ9XJJZNkOGDHgMdFl02YAyHwDsuzEfwGH2E9sDwK0vydF08AMTCh0eC8r1w-DkGY692NvB9BHoMjny8N9KLgx5qOdEBkCeXB6C+ANGOEPgBFYhMZ3+VMoKXPMs1XddNwLfjeH4QQMLbMTaOkuTYMeLAlD0VR0DUZTpyTWcxkgxc1wQRSoH0shFBAawHOEttkDMiSLLgrC4NsSxAscvCVJctT3MzTzvN8sxYrsmwTNEwFxLoyyWCioA)